# redirect standard output MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have

```
myFile = fullfile(x,'myFile.txt');
```

I would like to redirect stdout to print the content of myFile in console

is there a known function doing that ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to print the content of the variable, or of the text file? In the first case remove the semicolon at the end. Otherwise just read the file and print its contents/

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to read text file is using `urlread`

```
myfile=['file:///' fullfile(x,'myFile.txt')];
str = urlread(myfile)
```

as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myFile = fullfile(x,'myFile.txt');
textread (myfile)
```

textread function provide different options about the format of the file. you can find more details in help of textread.

Comment: If I check the doc it says: `Note:   textread is not recommended. Use textscan instead.` Unfortunately it doesn't state why, but usually its good to follow advice in the documentation.